# "panic: execution timeout at bigInt:1" happens since I raised version to 1.11.5

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node

##### System information

Geth version: `v1.11.5`

CL client & version: prysmaticlabs/prysm@v4.0.1

OS & Version: Linux(AmazonLinux)

vCPU: 8

RAM: 32GB

storage:

type: gp3
size: 2000 GiB
IOPS: 3000
throughput: 125

##### Expected behaviour

no panic

##### Actual behaviour

geth got panic

##### Steps to reproduce the behaviour

I have encountered the following PANIC at least twice since I raised it to 1.11.5 on 4/10 and geth stopped.

- running option added this time

```
--db.engine pebble
```

##### Backtrace

```
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: panic: execution timeout at bigInt:1:23925(46) [recovered]
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: panic: execution timeout at bigInt:1:23925(46) [recovered]
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: panic: execution timeout at bigInt:1:23925(46) [recovered]
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: panic: execution timeout at bigInt:1:23925(46)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: goroutine 2132519 [running]:
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json.(*encodeState).marshal.func1()
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json/encode.go:326 +0x6e
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: panic({0x1817080, 0xc0a9407700})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: runtime/panic.go:884 +0x213
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*vm).handleThrow(0xc095f18d80, {0x1817080, 0xc0a9407700})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/vm.go:730 +0x3b8
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*vm).try.func1()
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/vm.go:749 +0x45
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: panic({0x1817080, 0xc0a9407700})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: runtime/panic.go:884 +0x213
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*vm).handleThrow(0xc095f18d80, {0x1817080, 0xc0a9407700})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/vm.go:730 +0x3b8
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*vm).runTryInner.func1()
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/vm.go:772 +0x45
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: panic({0x1817080, 0xc0a9407700})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: runtime/panic.go:884 +0x213
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*vm).run(0xc095f18d80)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/vm.go:577 +0x133
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*vm).runTryInner(0xc095f18d80?)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/vm.go:776 +0x70
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*baseJsFuncObject).__call(0xc02e059d40, {0xc00a2e8800?, 0x1, 0xc00a2e87f0?}, {0x0?, 0x0}, {0x1cb46c8?, 0xc056e43470?})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/func.go:378 +0x705
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*baseJsFuncObject)._call(...)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/func.go:394
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*baseJsFuncObject).call(0x1674d80?, {{0x1cb46c8, 0xc056e43470}, {0xc00a2e8800, 0x1, 0x1}}, {0x0?, 0x0?})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/func.go:402 +0x7a
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*baseJsFuncObject).Call(...)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/func.go:334
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*_builtinJSON_stringifyContext).str(0xc01b859810, {0x1cb4c20?, 0xc00a2e87b0?}, 0xc056e43140)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/builtin_json.go:283 +0x1e9
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*_builtinJSON_stringifyContext).jo(0xc01b859810, 0xc056e43140)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/builtin_json.go:454 +0x2d3
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*_builtinJSON_stringifyContext).str(0xc01b859810, {0x1cb4c20?, 0xc00a2e87a0?}, 0xc0c5ab7620)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/builtin_json.go:368 +0x92f
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*_builtinJSON_stringifyContext).ja(0xc01b859810, 0xc0c5ab7620)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/builtin_json.go:402 +0x225
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*_builtinJSON_stringifyContext).str(0xc01b859810, {0x1cb4c20?, 0x2b39240?}, 0xc0a2e78c30)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/builtin_json.go:366 +0x91b
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*_builtinJSON_stringifyContext).do(0xc01b859810, {0x1cb46c8, 0xc0c5ab7620})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/builtin_json.go:274 +0x28e
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*Object).MarshalJSON.func1()
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/value.go:928 +0x2d
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*vm).try(0xc095f18d80, 0xc01b8597f8)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/vm.go:753 +0x242
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja.(*Object).MarshalJSON(0x19171e0?)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/dop251/goja@v0.0.0-20230122112309-96b1610dd4f7/value.go:927 +0x97
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json.marshalerEncoder(0xc03903ec80, {0x19171e0?, 0xc0c5ab7620?, 0xc0121323c0?}, {0x0?, 0x0?})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json/encode.go:477 +0xbe
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json.(*encodeState).reflectValue(0xc01b8599d0?, {0x19171e0?, 0xc0c5ab7620?, 0x1?}, {0x0?, 0x28?})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json/encode.go:358 +0x78
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json.(*encodeState).marshal(0xc0041ba400?, {0x19171e0?, 0xc0c5ab7620?}, {0x0?, 0x0?})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json/encode.go:330 +0xfa
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json.Marshal({0x19171e0, 0xc0c5ab7620})
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: encoding/json/encode.go:161 +0xe5
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/tracers/js.(*jsTracer).GetResult(0xc0313faff0)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/tracers/js/goja.go:348 +0x151
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/tracers.(*API).traceTx(0xc000197400, {0x1ca68d8, 0xc01de16640}, 0xc0cda914d0, 0xc02de52140, {0x1addc40, 0x1addc48, 0xc07a8666f0, {0xda, 0xfe, ...}, ...}, ...)
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/tracers/api.go:992 +0x769
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/tracers.(*API).traceBlockParallel.func1()
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/tracers/api.go:681 +0x625
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/tracers.(*API).traceBlockParallel
Apr  9 17:52:25 geth: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/tracers/api.go:670 +0x3bd
Apr  9 17:52:26 systemd: geth.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

why does this happen?